# No ZF2 como setar um valor em um Zend\Form\Element\Text na view?

Tags: php, zend, framework

### O Form:

```php
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'valor',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'maxlength' => '100'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                          'value' => 10, //Coloquei este valor de propósito
            )
    ));
```

### A view:

```php
$form->get('valor')
```

#### print_r() do form de valor:

```
Zend\Form\Element\Text Object ( 
  [attributes:protected] => Array ( 
        [type] => text 
        [name] => valor 
        [required] => 1      
        [class] => form-control [maxlength] => 100 
   ) 
   [label:protected] => [labelAttributes:protected] => Array ()                        
   [labelOptions:protected] => Array ( ) 
   [messages:protected] => Array ( ) 
   [options:protected] => Array ( [value] => 10 ) [value:protected] => 
   )
```

## ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve definir este valor no controller:

`$form->setData(['valor' => 'meu valor']);`

E, apesar de ser uma gambiarra, você pode utilizar este código acima antes do `$form->prepare` na view.

Caso você queira definir um valor padrão, em vez de colocar o 'value' dentro do options, coloque dentro dos atributos:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'valor',
    'type' => 'Text',
    'attributes' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'maxlength' => '100',
        'value' => 10
    ),
    'options' => array(
    )
));
```